# Why does the new key show different when we use Object.defineProperty() in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

In this example bellow (source: [W3school](https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_object_es5_6)), when we put `console.log('person',person);` in the end, `fullName` is in a different color in the log of others ([see the pic](https://postimg.cc/dDtn3rCm)). Does it mean  that `fullname` is temporary? What should I do to make it become part of `person`?

P.s: I'm begginner and I'm not able to put pictures here. thanks for understanding!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>JavaScript Object.defineProperty()</h2>

<p>This example uses the defineProperty() method to add a getter and a setter.</p>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
// Create an object:
const person = {firstName:"John", lastName:"Doe"};

// Define a getter
Object.defineProperty(person, "fullName", {
  get: function () {return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;}
});
console.log('person',person);
// Display full name
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = person.fullName;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Non-enumerable properties get colored slightly differently.

Comment: Thanks! But  is it Non-enumerable  because of a performance issue?

Comment: Nothing to do with performance, everything to do with enumerability